# Why shouldn't shorts use integer literals?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, language-lawyer, literals

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal),
the following statement would be invalid C++:

```
unsigned short test = 5u;
```

[image]

Why is using the suffix `u` or `U` not allowed on unsigned shorts?
The code still compiles, but are there any ramifications to doing this?

Comment: It *is* valid as long as the value is within the limits of the smaller type (`unsigned short` in your case). The compiler simply converts it to the correct type. Read more about [implicit conversions here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), especially the section about [integral conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_conversions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`5u` is not of type `unsigned short`, but that doesn't mean that `unsigned short test = 5u;` is "illegal".

The usual conversions occur.  As all `unsigned int`s are modulo `2^n` for some `n`, this simply truncates the value on the right hand side "bit wise".  So long as the rhs value fits in a short, nothing happens; if it does not, the "low order bits" are taken.

I speak about "bits" in quotes, as it is really math modulo `2^n` for some value of `n` under the standard.  Which is the same as bits, but there is no requirement that the C++ environment actually implement it using the obvious layout.

Answer (score 4):

You are misreading cppreference. What it says (not in these words) is:

- a literal ending in U is an `unsigned int` (or `unsigned long int` or `unsigned long long int`)

Note that it does not say anything about 'invalid' etc.

In your example

`unsigned short test = 5u;`

The `5u` literal *is* an `unsigned int`.

The variable `test` is *not* an `unsigned int`. It is an `unsigned short`. The compiler inserts an implicit cast, which is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 1):

That table on preference is table 6 from [lex.icon]

[image]

The reason `short` is not discussed is that the smallest type an integer literal can be is an `int`(from the suffix none part).  Since an `int` is guaranteed to be the same size or larger than an `int` there is no reason to call out `short`.

```
unsigned short test = 5u;
```

Is valid and it will implicitly convert `5u` to an `unsigned short`

Answer (score 0):

cppreference also says:

> The type of the integer literal is the first type in which the value can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base and which *integer-suffix* was used.

This means that `5u` is an `unsigned int` as 5 is within the range of that type.

If the value is too large, like `9887766554433u`, it will be an `unsigned long` if that type is wider than `unsigned int` and can hold the value, otherwise the type will be `unsigned long long`.

This matters, for example, if you use `auto` to declare your variable:

```
const auto x = 9887766554433u;
```

Here `x` will be of a type sufficiently large to hold the value.